# Documentation for migrating from Gatling 1.x to 2.0?

Tags: gatling

I have been bit by a bug in the JSON parser in Gatling 1.5.5 which I read is solved by migrating to 2.0.

The challenge is, there is very little documentation (that I have been able to find) on Gatling 2, aside from:  https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Gatling%202.

What state is the complete 2.0 documentation in, and is it accessible online yet?  If so, can I get a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upcoming Gatling 2 documentation (targeting current snapshot) is now [stored in the repository](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/tree/master/src/sphinx), along with the sources.